# Как связать переменные с двух файлов функции

Tags: matlab

Вот первый файл funct.m

```
function [x,y] = funct(t)
x = ((t.^2)+1).*sin(2.*t);
y = t.*cos(t);
```

Вот второй файл pasul.m

```
function [t,fig] = pasul(z,a)
t = [0:z:2*pi];
fig = figure(a);
```

И сам исполн. файл

```
pasul(0.05,1);
funct(pasul);
plot(funct,'*-');
comet(funct,'*-');
xlabel('x');
ylabel('y');
title('y(x)');
legend('y(x)',0);
```

В задании дано чтобы я создал 1 файл функцию для определения xy(t) и отдельный файл где вводные значения будут номер фигуры и сам шаг в значении t
Тут я попытался что то сделать но увы я не могу связать полученое значение t с файла pasul в файле funct дабы узнать x и y

Answer (score 0):

```
clc
clear
[t,fig]=pasul(0.05,1);%здесь можно получить переменную t
[x,y]=funct(t);%здесь ты получишь переменные для построения графика
plot(x,y,'*-');
xlabel('x');ylabel('y');%и прочие настройки графика без изменений
hold on %иначе у тебя не будет наложения графиков, это команда разрешает строить один график поверх другого
comet(x,y,p)%где p - длина хвоста кометы от 0 до 1
```

Комете нельзя присваивать параметры линий, только длину следа. Проверил у себя - все работает.